# How to export and import a function from a Class Component

Tags: reactjs, html-framework-7

I have a class component and inside i wanna define some functions to use them in other components.

I´m working with Framework7 and to use features like Dialogs it has to be a class component.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
class myComponent extends Component {
   firstFunction = () => { // code };

   secondFunction = () => { // code };
}

export { firstFunction, secondFunction }
```

```
import { firstFunction from './filename'}
```

I was hoping to build a component that holds these functions so i can use them wherever i import them but it seems like i´m on the wrong way here.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this is an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem? What is it exactly that your two functions are doing? There might be a better way to solve the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ref`. (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

When you are using your component, you can assign it a ref to have access to all its methods:

```
<MyComponent ref={ref => this.myComponentRef = ref} />
```

then:

```
this.myComponentRef.firstFunction()
```